# How to write a formal proof of the statement: For all integers n, if n is a multiple of 5 then 3n is a multiple of 5.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

**Prove:**  *For all integers $n$, if $n$ is a multiple of $5$ then $3n$ is a multiple of $5$*.

*Proof:* Assume $n$ is a multiple of $5$. Then $n$ must have the form $5k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. We have the following sequence of implications:
$5k \Rightarrow n$ (by assumption) $\Rightarrow 3n.$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: What does "$5k \Rightarrow n$" even mean?

Comment: What am trying to say is that 5k | 5, since any number times 5 is a multiple of 5?

Comment: Note: I assume you meant to write $5 | 5k$.  What you've written is "$5k$ divides 5", which is false unless $k = 1$.

Comment: @AlexMiller, you are correct sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written that $n \implies 3n$, but that's not really an "implication".  You need to show that if a number is divisible by $5$, then $3$ times that number is also divisible by $5$.  So given a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that is divisible by $5$, you have that $n = 5k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  It follows that $$n = 5k \implies 3n = 15k$$

But $15k = 5(3k)$, and $3k$ is clearly also an integer, so if we let $3k = C$ where $C$ is an integer, then $3n = 5C$, which means $3n$ is also divisible by $5$.

Answer (score 2):

By assumption, $n = 5k$. So $3n = 3\cdot5k = 5\cdot 3k$, by commutativity of multiplication. Hence $5|(3n)$.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the sequence of implications with "then $3n=5(3k)$, so $3n$ is a multiple of $5$"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by direct proof?

Assume $n$ is a multiple of $5$.

$$\therefore n = 5k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$\therefore 3n = 3(5k)=5(3k)$$
and $3k\in \mathbb{Z}$ so that,
$$\therefore 3n = 5(l), l \in \mathbb{Z}$$
hence $3n$ is a multiple of 5